# When should I use Loaders? and when asynctask? (Android)

Tags: android, sqlite, android-asynctask, loader

I am still confused. I have read several tutorials of loaders and asynctask in Android but I can't understand some differences in some cases. For example:

**Your app can't continue without the information which is provided by Asynctask or Loader**

- If you need information from MySQL database, what will be better?
- And...What if you need information from SQLite database?
- Maybe, you might need data from a url.

**Your app can continue without the information which is provided by Asynctask or Loader**

- If you need information from MySQL database, what will be better?
- And...What if you need information from SQLite database?
- Maybe, you might need data from a url.

If you consider we must mention more differences or other case, you can write it.

Comment: You can always use the AsyncTaskLoader if you doubt.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, both of them are used to perform asynchronous operations, it doesn't really matter if your app can or can't continue without the information. Even if your app can continue wihtout the data, you still need to process it asynchronously to avoid an ANR message.

One reason to choose a Loader or an AsyncTask would be if you need to get data updates. The advantage of the Loaders is that they keep track of the data you are accessing and deliver new results when the data changes.

Other difference is that with Loaders you don't have to worry about configuration changes (orientation change e.g.). The LoaderManager takes care of that for you. With AsyncTask you need to take care of that yourself.

And there is even an AsyncTaskLoader, that does what AsyncTask does but with the benefits of Loaders.

The advantage of AsyncTask is that is very simple to use. If you don't need to load or monitor data, but just process something in the background. AsyncTask is still a good choice.

Answer (score 0):

Cursors are simply used to reconnect to the last cursor onec it has been interrupted for a reason. They are usually designed to use in fragments or activitys.

Documentation for Loaders:

They are available to every Activity and Fragment.
They provide asynchronous loading of data.
They monitor the source of their data and deliver new results when the content changes.
They automatically reconnect to the last loader's cursor when being recreated after a configuration change. Thus, they don't need to re-query their data.

Asynctask are more likely a wrapper which contains a whole subset of methods to access the mainUI and background thread.